# In my models.py, one ForeignKey declaration does not require a default, but the other does? Why?

Tags: python, django

In attempting to run `manage.py makemigrations`, I received the following error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'menu_category' to fooditem without 
a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing
rows.
```

My code is as follows:

## models.py

```
class FoodItem(models.model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_category = models.ForeignKey('MenuCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

The part that doesn't make sense is that no error occurs when I remove the menu_category line, despite the fact that the restaurant foreign key does not have a default either. Also, if I must specify a default value for a foreign key, what value would I even specify?

Comment: You have rows in your DB with existing values for "menu_category." Thus, Django expects a default value for new ones. You're only seeing this error because of the existing values for that property; otherwise you'd be able to correctly define your foreign key without a default.

Comment: Is there any way I can get rid of the existing values? Also, I don't know how  I could have existing values seeing as I had just created this field; I haven't ever migrated it.

Comment: The existing "values" are most likely null, but they still technically occupy space in your table. You might be able to delete the offending rows altogether if it doesn't result in too much rework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding only a single new column called `menu_category`, right? The `restaurant` field does not give errors because it already exists.

Django gives you this error because you are adding a field that can't be null to a table that already exists without a default value. You either need to allow nulls (so the created column values can be empty in rows that already exist) or specify a default value to fill the column with.

Django should be asking you if you want to provide a "one-off" default value just for the migation. If you have some "default" menu category that the `FoodItem` objects can have, then specify its id when django prompts you for a value.

Example prmopt:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations 
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'menu_category' to fooditem without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
>>> 1
Migrations for 'my_app':
  0002_fooditem_menu_category.py:
    - Add field menu_category to fooditem
```

Comment: The default value that I would provide is automatically interpreted as the id of the foreign key? What would happen if I were to input a string?

Comment: Yes, it's the foreign key id. If you specified a string, you would get an error when applying the migration. You can always edit the migration manually to fix any errors and try again.